# all brushes draw differently on different sides

Tags: sculpting, geometry, brushes

when I use any brush in sculpting mode, I have a problem with how brush work. All brushes draw differently on different sides.[image]

That how it looks after I draw. It's like I used CTRL with one side, but I didn't.
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked if some of the faces are flipped? The face normal determines in which way the sculpting is applied.

Comment: I'll add a screenshot with normals

Answer (score 0):

In the following screenshot, some parts of the mesh are indented and some are bulged - using the same brush, not switching any setting:

[image: sculpted mesh]

If you enable *Overlays* > *Face Orientation*, you can see that the indented parts are showing in red. The face normals are flipped with their inside out. To repair it, select all in *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals so that they are all blue.

[image: flipped faces]

Comment: its not worked.

Comment: @TheNelloY Yeah sorry, after I saw your edited question with normals it didn't seem like this could be the solution. I'll leave it here for people with similar problems. Maybe you have to upload your file.